# Symetric XML parsing and printing

Tags: java, android, xml, saxparser

I am looking for a way to parse and print (slighly changed) XML such that the content of elements stays unchanged, even if it contains escaped and unescaped greater than or less than signs (i.e. > as well as > or < and < ).
SaxHandler returns a > or < character even if the source contained the escaped way of writing it. But I need to know, whether it was escaped or written as single sign.

Why do I need that:
I like to keep my strings.xml file sorted by the name attribute.
Therefore I am parsing the file, sort the string elements by the name attribute, and print it out again.
Unfortunately a file which looks e.g. like that:

```
<resources>
    <string name="B">--&gt;</string>
    <string name="C">--></string>
    <string name="A">&lt;--</string>
</resources>
```

is changed after parsing and sorting to:

```
<resources>
    <string name="A"><--</string>
    <string name="B">--></string>
    <string name="C">--></string>
</resources>
```

where the string A contains invalid XML.

Is there an easy way, still using an standard XML parser, to get the raw content of an element.

Comment: "SaxHandler returns a > or < character even if the source contained the escaped way of writing it" -- it should return `<` or `>` *only* if the source contained the escaped way of writing it, or it was in a `CDATA`. Otherwise, those are part of an element name, and you will not get the raw characters.

Comment: I think it's ok for a greater than sign, if there is no preceding less than sign, as in the example of string C above. But I think my problem was the re-escaping of the content before printing, instead of immediately while parsing. I am keeping the whole content of the "string" element in one variable, even if it contains html-formatting like <b>. When printing this variable it is difficult to distinguish whether the lt and gt signs are to be escaped or not. But while parsing, it is obvious whether its content or an (HTML formatting) element.